# What is the Preboot Folder?

Tags: folders, high-sierra

Could someone tell what is the `Preboot` folder in `/Volumes` and may I delete it?

```
$ ls -l /Volumes/
total 0
0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   1 Oct 20 12:13 Macintosh HD -> /
0 drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root  wheel  96 Sep 26 11:25 Preboot
```

UPD: Here is the [files list](https://xdrops.in/VoD0Q0lXXqMg59ta5pRxBX7Y.txt) inside `Preboot` folder.

Comment: Another buggy construct. I have two...

lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   1 Dec 23 10:43 C -> /
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root  wheel  96 Sep 16 08:11 Preboot
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root  wheel  96 Oct  7 15:59 Preboot 1
drwx--x--x+ 3 root  wheel  96 Dec 23 09:49 com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made backup and delete this folder. Everything is working fine. So I think this folder is a part of update process of something like this.

Comment: Hi, may I ask you, do you have your disk encrypted? I found some info that Preboot folder might be related and needed when you have your disk encrypted. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Yes. It was encrypted from the beginning. So it's not related.

Answer (score 8):

The Preboot volume is a new system partition that manages boot, the partition is created during the update to macOS High Sierra to support booting to an APFS volume(The one named Macintosh HD).
APFS is a new filesystem created by Apple, and it makes a lot of changes([link to Wikipedia article about APFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System#Design)), and one of them is the addition of the Preboot volume, which is required to boot APFS, so if you delete it, you can't boot!

Comment: Are you sure your other Mac uses APFS?, 
Macs with fusion drives doesn't use/support APFS, at the moment...

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. I'm already checked two Macs about this folder.

Comment: I didn't have any Preboot partition because I upgraded to High Sierra as opposed to installing it from scratch. Then High sierra refused to encrypt my disk (enable FileVault)  until I had a Preboot partition. The only way I found I could create a Preboot partition is by re-installing from scratch from createinstallmedia

Comment: All you write is likely correct about the Preboot volume. But at least here, `/Volumes/Preboot` is a folder that is *not* related to the volume — `mount` does not show that volume (here /dev/disk1s2) mounted there. Moreover, if I mount the volume by hand, the contents of the volume are not identical to the contents of the folder, tho those folders might be outdated copies.

Answer (score 0):

If you find one or more "Preboot" folder at the root of your disk after upgrading to macOS Catalina (10.15), you can hide them with the following method:

1. Disable SIP (you'll have to boot into the Recovery system for that), e.g. see https://support.studionetworksolutions.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003839246-How-to-disable-Systems-Integrity-Protection-SIP-in-macOS
2. Once back in normal Catalina, go into Terminal and enter: "sudo mount -uw /". This makes the system volume writable (which is read-only by default since Catalina).
3. Now hide the Preboot folder with these Terminal commands (only one is needed but I don't know which - if you figured it out, leave a comment and I'll update this answer):

```
sudo chflags hidden /Volumes/Preboot*
sudo chflags hidden /Preboot*
```

4. Now you can enable SIP again.